# Problems with initializing classes in iphone development

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, initialization

Hey guys sorry for the noob question but I am having a hard time initializing my self created classes for an iphone game I've started making. Before I started actually developing my game I ran a quick test to see if what I have already would work, and the class that I was testing wouldn't initialize. Here is what I have:

```
    @implementation Game
    SceneController *sceneController;

    +(id)scene {...} // just the default scene method created by cocos2d

    -(id)init{
        if((self=[super init])){
            [[sceneController performSelector:@selector(alloc)]performSelector:@selector(init)];
            CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
            CCLabelTTF *label=[CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[sceneController performSelector:@selector(xxx)]] fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:64];
            [self addChild: label];
        }
        return self;
    }


    // IN ANOTHER CLASS
    @implementation SceneController
    int xxx; // not a real variable just used for the test

    -(id)init{
        if((self=[super init])){
            xxx=432;
        }
        return self;
    }

    -(int)xxx{
        return xxx;
    }
```

My problem is that instead of the label reading 432 like it should it just says 0. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't contructed your `SceneController` object correctly.

In your `init` method of Game, you need to make a call like this:

`sceneController = [[SceneController alloc] init];`

instead of this:

`[[sceneController performSelector:@selector(alloc)]performSelector:@selector(init)];`

Then your `sceneController` instance variable is properly initialised and your `init` method will have been called.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[sceneController performSelector:@selector(alloc)] performSelector:@selector(init)];
```

Wow. That's like entering the car through the trunk. Funny this still works though. Or maybe it doesn't and that's why you get the error.

Anyhow, to iniatialize a class (and any Objective-C tutorial will teach you that) you do this:

```
sceneController = [[SceneController alloc] init];
```

You should also add a breakpoint to the init method to test if it actually runs.